In Azure DevOps Pipeline, how to pass an array of objects from output variable to a template as parameter?
I'm building a variable made of array of objects and can somehow pass it to another job from another stage, and can even print its value. But it seems I'm not passing it properly as a parameter to the template and I'm getting this error:

/templates/process-apps-template.yml (Line: 16, Col: 3): Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(apps)'

And here are my codes
# applications-pipeline.yml
stages:
  - stage: Initialize
    displayName: Initialize
    jobs:
    - task: Bash@3
      name: Applications
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/01_applications'
        script: |
          # simplified code, the actual one was very long
          applications=(
            '{"application": "app1", "environments": ["dev", "test", "production"]}'
            '{"application": "app2", "environments": ["dev", "staging"]}'
          )
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apps;isOutput=true]${applications[@]}"

  - stage: ProcessApps
    dependsOn: [Initialize]
    variables: 
      - name: apps
        value: $[ stageDependencies.Initialize.AppsList.outputs['Applications.apps'] ]
    jobs:    
      - template: templates/process-apps-template.yml
        parameters:
          apps: $(apps)


# templates/process-apps-template.yml
parameters:
- name: apps
  type: object
  default: []

jobs:
- job: PaceholderJob

- ${{ each app in parameters.apps }}:
  - job: ProcApp
    steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            echo ${{ app.application }}

Also, how to append the "app.application" to the name and display name of the job "ProcApp"?

The Output variable in pipeline will expand at runtime. But the template parameters will read the variable at compile time. So we are not able to pass the output variable to template in a single pipeline. I have shared a workaround about splitting the pipeline into two to achieve your requirement. You can refer it


/templates/process-apps-template.yml (Line: 16, Col: 3): Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(apps)'

The cause of the issue is that the variable: $(apps) is Runtime variable(Expand at Runtime) and the template will read the variable at compile time. In this case, the Runtime variable value can not be read by the YAML template.
I am afraid that your requirement can not be achieved in a single pipeline.

how to append the "app.application" to the name and display name of the job "ProcApp"?

To meet your requirement, you can split the two stages into two pipelines. One is used to run Initialize stage. It will set the Pipeline variable and trigger the other pipeline with the required array. The other pipeline is used to run ProcessApps stage and it will collect the array object.
Here is an example:
Pipeline One:
stages:
  - stage: Initialize
    displayName: Initialize
    jobs:
    - job: AppsList
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        name: Applications
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
   
            applications=(
              '{"application": "app1", "environments": ["dev", "test", "production"]},'
              '{"application": "app2", "environments": ["dev", "staging"]}'
            )
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apps;isOutput=true]${applications[@]}"

      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              az pipelines run --id {PipelineID} --organization $(System.CollectionUri) --project {ProjectName} --parameters Passapps="[$(Applications.apps)]"
        env:
         AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(PAT)

Note: You can use the following format to set the variable value:
        applications=(
          '{"application": "app1", "environments": ["dev", "test", "production"]},'
          '{"application": "app2", "environments": ["dev", "staging"]}'
        )

Pipeline Two:
Main YAML:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: Passapps
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- stage: ProcessApps
  jobs:    
    - template: templates/process-apps-template.yml
      parameters:
        apps: ${{parameters.Passapps}}

Template:
parameters:
- name: apps
  type: object
  default: []

jobs:
- job: PaceholderJob

- ${{ each app in parameters.apps }}:
  - job: ${{ app.application }}
    steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            echo ${{ app.application }}

Result:

Here is the doc related to Azure DevOps CLI trigger Pipeline: az pipelines run

Thanks! I never knew you can execute a pipeline through a script. Anyway, I'm trying to analyze the newly added section, are the PipelineID and ProjectName some kind of predefined variables? I'm looking at the documentation and can't find them in there. Same with the PAT variable.

@eSPiYa You can hardcode the PipelineID and the ProjectName in the script. And the PAT is custom variable. You need to generate a PAT and set it in the variable. Or you can use the $(system.accesstoken). But in this case, you need to grant the required permissions to the build service account. You can have a try first. Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.

Thanks! It worked! I just merged up the template to the main yaml.
